# SwiftUI - seeing ghost edge of a conditional view when transitioning a view with a rotation3DEffect

Tags: swiftui

I've been trying to use an animated transition with rotation3DEffect for a conditional view in an App.  But I'm seeing random ghost-edges of the conditional view when it should be hidden.
See the example code and images.  Has anyone seen a similar issue and know what the issue is?  As a separate but more minor issue, the canvas doesn't render the insertion transition, but it works fine in the simulator. Thanks.

```
struct RotateView3DModifer: ViewModifier {
var angleDegrees: Double

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.rotation3DEffect(
        Angle(degrees: angleDegrees),
        axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0) )
}
```

}

```
extension AnyTransition {
static var rotateInOut: AnyTransition {
    
    let insertion = AnyTransition.modifier(
            active: RotateView3DModifer(angleDegrees: -90),
            identity: RotateView3DModifer(angleDegrees: 45) )
    
    let removal = AnyTransition.modifier(
            active: RotateView3DModifer(angleDegrees: 90),
            identity: RotateView3DModifer(angleDegrees: 0) )
    
    return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var show: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(
            action: { withAnimation { show.toggle() }},
            label: { Text("\(show ? "Showing" : "Hidden")") } )
        
        VStack {
            if (show) {
                Rectangle()
                    .transition(.rotateInOut)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
    }
}
```

}

[When showing the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRyXZ.png)
[image: Ghost edge still showing when view hidden]

Comment: It looks like a simulator bug, did you try on a device?

Comment: Yep - indeed - finally tried on an actual device and no ghost edges.  Looks like a bug in the simulator and the canvas (the canvas is worse as also doesn't seem to like asymmetric insertion transitions).  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed it's an issue with the simulator and the canvas.  No ghost edges appear on an actual device.